# Do the error numbers in exceptions match between the Mill and Lathe API?

Tags: okuma

Are the error numbers that are in the exceptions thrown by the API consistent for methods with the same name and signature between Mills and Lathes?

`E01013002` is always the error code when an improper 'screen name' is passed to `CMCMDAPI.CViews.ChangeScreen` or `CLCMDAPI.CViews.ChangeScreen`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error numbers are not the same. Since they are different platforms with a different set of possible errors, an effort was not made to make them match.

Some of the earlier error messages may match but assume it is coincidence -- don't count on newer ones matching.